# instantiate a generic class in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to instantiate an object with a generic type in Dart.

So far, there is nothing very complicated. This is how I would normally do it:

```
MyClass <MyType> x = new MyClass <MyType> ();
```

However, there I have a somewhat special case. The "MyType" type I want to use is contained in a variable.
And there, I do not see how to do the instantiation.
I specify that it is for a Flutter project.
Could you help me please ?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information about your question? I'm failing to see what you mean by "type is contained in a variable"

Answer (score 1):

This way you can create a generic class and customize it to your needing:

```
class GenericClass<T> {
  T t;

  T getModel() => t;

  void setModel(T t) => this.t = t;
}
```

You can also define its type to extends your 'CustomModel':

```
class GenericClass<T extends CustomModel>{
   ...
}
```

For using just get instance from class like this:

```
GenericClass<int> intClass = new GenericClass();
```

I hope it was useful for you :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no path without using something reflective like `dart:mirrors` to go from a String to a type.  This is by design, to allow tree-shaking and optimizations to be more productive.

Comment: Thanks.
But dart:mirros does not exist for flutter project.
I use reflectable.
I need an extract of code.

Comment: Soon.  Soon we'll have macros.  And that will enable a lot more reflection at compile time!